# I can't update my computer

Tags: macos, mac, gopro

My Mac OS X won't let me update past version 10.6.8.

When I check for a software update is says I have the latest software (which I don't).

I need to update to use my go pro editing software but I can't update.

Comment: Do check if your Mac hardware supports the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

OS X always checks for the latest version of OS X installed on that Mac. As 10.6.8 is the latest version of Snow Leopard, it will tell you that you are running latest version. But if you want to run the newest OS X Yosemite, check whether it is supported by your Mac or not on Apple website.